# how to use opengl transform feedback, I always get 0 in the buffers

Tags: opengl

I was trying to use transform feedback to retrieve data from vertex shader for debugging as my perspective matrix seemed to be miscalculated.  I got nothing in the transform feedback buffer. Can anyone help me figure out which step I did wrong?

Following is snippet of my code of setting up transform feedback:

```
//vertex to be passed into shader
const float vertexPos[] =
{
     0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

//set up transform feedback
const char *variableName = "retrieve";//the variable to be retreived in shader
float dateFromShader[16];//receive the data from shader
GLuint tf_bo;//transform feedback buffer id

glTransformFeedbackVaryings(shaderProgram, 1, &variableName, GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

glGenBuffers(1, &tf_bo);
glBindBuffer(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, tf_bo);// Is this necessary to call glBindBuffer before glBindBufferBase?
     glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, tf_bo);
     glBufferDate(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 16, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
glBindBuffer(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0);

//retrieve data from vertex shader
glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DICARD);
glBindBuffer(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, tf_bo);
glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_TRIANGLES);
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);//
glEndTransformFeedback();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tf_bo);
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(float) * 16, dataFromShader);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
```

and my vertex shader is like this:

```
#version 420

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;


uniform mat4 perspectiveMatrix;
out mat4 retrieve;

void main()
{
gl_Position = perspectiveMatrix * position;

retrieve = perspectiveMatrix;
}
```

Comment: Since I don't have any experience with the transform feedback buffer, I can only recommend you try copying some of the online tutorials such as http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial28/tutorial28.html Secondly, are you checking OpenGl errors? It could be that something is going wrong but you don't know about it. Use [glGetError](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) to do this. If it returns an error, try to find out which call is generating it by moving the glGetError call around. Thirdly, this seems like a VERY complicated way to debug your perspective matrix. A far bett

Comment: thank you for your advice, I will try to check the prespective matrix in the application code not shader. I think I will need to use transform feedback later anyway, so I'd better learn it through for future use.

Answer (score 5):

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, tf_bo);
```

As stated [in the documentation, `glBindBufferBase`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindBufferBase#Errors) requires that the buffer object have data storage (ie: that you have called `glBufferData` on it). `glBindBufferBase` is not a *replacement* for `glBindBuffer`; is a different kind of function that has a different use.

Next, you're capturing a matrix. The problem is that you're drawing *three vertices*, which means that you're going to capture three vertices. You only allocated enough space for one. That's going to cause undefined behavior.

Most importantly of all... what exactly do you think this will accomplish? You're capturing a uniform value *you directly uploaded*. Unless you believe that the implementation's version of glUniformMatrix is broken in some way, that's not very helpful in debugging anything.

Comment: Thank you for your help. from the result of perspective matrix multiplied by vertex which I did manually, I think my perspective matrix is correct. But why my triangle was visible only when the transformed z value is negative? since [n,f] is mapped to [-1, 1] in clipping space, so I think points of 0 < z < 1 should also be visible which is not the case in my situation. I even directly passed vertices with 0 < z < 1 and w = 1.0 to shader without perspective transformation(which means they are already in clipping space, right?), still I got nothing.

Comment: @CGPhaha: This is a different question that has nothing to do with feedback rendering. You should use the "Ask Question" button to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 glBufferDate(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 16, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
```

Is this line not supposed to be:

```
 glBufferData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 16, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
```

Note the "glBufferData" not "glBufferDate". This will also support the fact that you are not getting any data in the buffer / 0 is being returned....